# How to reverse Greek letters with BufferedReader in Java?

Tags: java, letter

I am new to Java and I have this Reverse code. My question is how can I use BufferedReader in order to when I write greek letters (like ξηφαιπασς) it will also return reversed greek letters. At the moment all I get is some squares. First time I write a question here so please forgive me for any mistake.

> import java.io.*;                 // for I/O
>   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>   class StackX
>        {
>        private int maxSize;
>        private char[] stackArray;
>        private int top;
>       //------------------------------------------------------------- 
>        public StackX(int max)     // constructor
>           {
>           maxSize = max;
>           stackArray = new char[maxSize];
>           top = -1;
>           }
>       //-------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
>  public char pop()         // take item from top of stack     
>     {     
>     return stackArray[top--];     
>     }     
>  //------------------------------------------------------------->  
>  public boolean isEmpty()  // true if stack is empty     
>     {     
>     return (top == -1);     
>     }     
> //-------------------------------------------------------------
>
>  }  // end class StackX     
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
> class Reverser     
>  {     
>  private String input;                // input string     
>  private String output;               // output string        >  
>  public Reverser(String in)           // constructor     
>     { input = in; }     
> //------------------------------------------------------------->  
>  public String doRev()                // reverse the string     
>     {     
>     int stackSize = input.length();   // get max stack size     
>     StackX theStack = new StackX(stackSize);  // make stack     
>
>     for(int j=0; j<input.length(); j++)     
>        {     
>        char ch = input.charAt(j);     // get a char from input 
>
>        theStack.push(ch);             // push it     
>        }     
>     output = "";     
>     while( !theStack.isEmpty() )     
>        {     
>        char ch = theStack.pop();      // pop a char,     
>        output = output + ch;          // append to output     
>        }     
>     return output;     
>     }  // end doRev()     
> //------------------------------------------------------------->  
>  }  // end class Reverser     
> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////          
>  class ReverseApp {     
>  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException     
>     {     
>     String input, output;     
>     while(true)     
>        {     
>        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");     
>        System.out.flush();     
>        input = getString();          // read a string from kbd 
>
>        if( input.equals("") )        // quit if [Enter]     
>           break;     
>                                      // make a Reverser     
>        Reverser theReverser = new Reverser(input);     
>        output = theReverser.doRev(); // use it     
>        System.out.println("Reversed: " + output);     
>        }  // end while     
>     }  // end main()     
> //-------------------------------------------------------------
>
>  public static String getString() throws IOException     
>     {     
>
>     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF8" ));     
>     String s = br.readLine();     
>     return s;     
>     }     
> //-------------------------------------------------------------
>
>  }  // end class ReverseApp
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "reversed greek letters"? Do you want to reverse a string?

Comment: Reverse a string which contains greek letters. Already got it thx:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change UTF8 to ISO-8859-7

Change

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF8" ));
```

To

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "ISO-8859-7"));
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question, you are basically trying to reverse a String and you are facing problem with unicode characters. Why don't you reverse using reverse() method of StringBuilder class -

```
String result=new StringBuilder("ξηφαιπασς").reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to check the encoding of the entered text: http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/